Trying to install Pyspark but after doing all my settings and path. Is showing path
please can I use Tableau public to connec to mongoDB?
I'm trying to connect Tableau public to Mongo DB but Mongo DB is not showing even SQL only Excel and csv that I can connect to.
I tried Tableau public is also showing error.
Please how do I resolve this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Try downloading the 14 day trial of Tableau Desktop
